# dropTable in liquibase erases all data from table, but the table it self is still available

Tags: java, mariadb, liquibase

In my little project here i got rid of a table which i want now to be droped using liquibase.
I created a new changeSet which will check if the table exists and if so it should drop the table.
The result i see is, that all data from the table is erased after execution but the tables are still present in the database.
I'm using mariadb, a simplified example of my changelog:

```
<databaseChangeLog
    xmlns="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-3.8.xsd">

<changeSet author="xx" id="create">
    <preConditions onFail="MARK_RAN">
        <not>
            <tableExists tableName="customer"/>
        </not>
    </preConditions>
    <createTable tableName="customer">
        <column name="id" type="BIGINT">
            <constraints nullable="false" primaryKey="true"/>
        </column>       
        <column name="name" type="VARCHAR(255)"/>
    </createTable>
</changeSet>

<changeSet id="drop" author="xx">
    <preConditions onFail="MARK_RAN">
        <tableExists tableName="customer" />
    </preConditions>
    <dropTable tableName="customer"/>
</changeSet>
```

I as well tried to do it manually using  DROP TABLE customer  in the changeSet but still the same result.
Does anyone have an idea what could be a solution or what i'm missing out?

Comment: Are you sure that the drop is executed after the create?

Comment: I tried your example with postgres DB, liquibase works fine there. It created the table and also dropped it. Could you check the output of `updateSQL` command once just to confirm the SQL getting executed are proper. Also it would be helpful if you could add the output of `updateSQL` command in your question itself.

Comment: Thanks for your help, i don't really know what happened but at the end in the productiv environment the drop did finally work. Why it did not in the local environment is a mystery for me.